# Apply multiple styles to a single Text - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know if there is a way to apply multiple styles to a text, here I apply a material theme to this text, but I also want to change this text size, how can I do it ? since I have already used the style attribute

```
    Text(text = "This is my default text", style = (MaterialTheme.typography).body1)
```

Also, how to add 2 modifiers , lets say I want to add padding and also a fillMaxWidth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the `TestStyle` you can use the [**`merge`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#merge) method.
Also if you want to use multiple modifiers you can **concatenated** them. In this case **the order affects the final result**.

Example:

```
Text(
    text = "This is my default text",
    style = (MaterialTheme.typography).body1
        .merge(TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp)),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 16.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Comment: I've seen @Preview "break" if .merge() is used for a style... unless you explicitly do a "Build & Refresh"..

Answer (score 4):

You can modify a [`TextStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle) by [copying](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#copy) it, for example:

```kotlin
Text(
    text = "This is my default text",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
        fontSize = 10.sp
    )
)
```

Comment: I've seen @Preview "break" if .copy() is used for a style... unless you explicitly do a "Build & Refresh"..